# How to execute Selenium script from Linux terminal

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, linux

I created a .bat file in Windows and launching it from the Windows console and it worked perfectly.
Now I got a requirement to execute it from Linux so the .bat file doesn't work, after searching I found you need to create a .sh file .

This is what I used:

```
export projectLocation=../Demo_Automatisation
cd $projectLocation
export classpath=$projectLocation/bin;$projectLocation/lib/*
java org.testng.TestNG $projectLocation/testng.xml
```

but I am getting an error:

```
ExecutionAuto.sh: line 3: ../Demo_Automatisation/lib/SparseBitSet-1.2.jar: Permission denied
+ java org.testng.TestNG ../Demo_Automatisation/testng.xml
Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.TestNG
```

I don't have the smallest clue about why is this happening, can someone assist me with this?

Comment: Linux is case sensitive, so I think it should be `CLASSPATH`, not `classpath`: `export CLASSPATH=$projectLocation/bin;$projectLocation/lib/*`

Comment: it did nothing i tried everything possible and i dont understand i am even executing it as sudo and i still get that permission denied

Comment: Hard to say, perhaps something wrong with your installation of java (what does `java -version` tell you?). Try to reinstall it. Install it with your package distro manager. "Permission denied" can also mean you don't have the execute bit set.

Comment: do the jar file not work in linux ?

Comment: You can bundle your Java code into a jar file and execute it in Linux. This will not be a problem.

Comment: No it s because i am having these errors ../Demo_Automatisation/lib/SparseBitSet-1.2.jar: line 1: $'PK\003\004': command not found
../Demo_Automatisation/lib/SparseBitSet-1.2.jar: line 2: $'ؔ\220L': command not found
../Demo_Automatisation/lib/SparseBitSet-1.2.jar: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Comment: use maven ? its easier than all this head ache

Answer (score 1):

To run your Selenium project via a terminal in Linux,

1. You can export your project into a JAR file and then execute that JAR file from the Terminal in Linux.

If you are using Eclipse, you can export your project as a runable JAR and package/extract your libraries into the JAR file.

[image]

Also, ensure required external libraries are in a proper/same folder as you might have set it up in your code.

[image]

Once done this, you can open terminal and then run this command,

```
java -jar /<path to your jar file>/name-of-file.jar
```

This should run your Selenium project via the terminal.

---

2. PS: Haven't tried this first hand.

If you are using **Maven or TestNG** you can also try this,

Make sure to compile your project code. In case of Eclipse, your compiled code can be found in your `eclipse-workspace/<your project folder>/bin` folder.

Also ensure that all your dependencies (Selenium or other) are in a single/central folder accessible by the project. All your JAR files should be within this folder.

So now, your project's directory structure will look something like this,

```
/bin - Has all test packages. Compiled code.
/src - Has all your source files. Un-compiled code.
/lib - All the required libraries.
```

Now, open the terminal and run these steps,

1. `set classpath=/<path to your project folder>/bin;/<path to your project folder>/lib/*`
2. `java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`

This should run your tests via the Terminal.

To execute particular test from the testng.xml file you can try

```
org.testng.TestNG -testnames “test-name-here” testng.xml
```

Comment: A runnable JAR file is a nice workaround until a proper way is available.

Answer (score 0):

```
java -cp "$projectLocation/bin:$projectLocation/lib/*"  org.testng.TestNG $projectLocation/testng.xml
```

Using colon instead of semicolon should fix this